# Using this VS setters in an extended class

Tags: java

Is there any reason I should not use setters instead of "super" and "this" to create a default object in an extended class?

Example

```
public class Foo{

    private String foo;

    public Foo(){
    }

    public Foo(String foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo){
        this.foo = foo;

}
```

Extended class using "this" to create a Bar with a preset String foo.

```
public class Bar extends Foo{

    public Bar(String foo){
        super(foo);
    }

    public Bar(){
        this("foobar");
    }
}
```

Extended class using setter to create a Bar with a preset String foo.

```
public class Bar extends Foo{

    public Bar(){
        setFoo("foobar");
    }
}
```

As far as I can see they both have the same result.
Is there any reason using setters for this purpose should be avoided?

Comment: no, they don't have the same result. The second one doesn't compile.

Comment: In order for your second `Bar` example to compile, `Foo` needs a parameter-less default constructor. Without an explicit `super` call in `Bar`'s constructor, an implicit call to the parent's default constructor is made.

Comment: Yep, sorry I forgot that. I edited the question to reflect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem but instead one asking for opinions over comparing functional examples where their functionality could have been answered by going through existing tutorials and resources.

Comment: So there is no problems in doing this?

Comment: Your code still behaves differently. Which one you should/could use still depends on your use-cases.

Comment: OK, thanks. That is the answer I need, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing with setters is not a good practice in my opinion, it makes the code less readable and more tightly coupled. If you initialize using setters, the person reading your constuctor code will need to also read the code in the setters to make sure nothing unexpected happens there. Also, if at some point someone needs to add some extra code to a setter she will need to check the effects that code has on the constructor.

Comment: Setters can change also, which might then break the constructor in the class `Bar`